# maxJsonLength when consuming WCF service using Jquery

Tags: wcf, jquery, jsonserializer

I am working on Google Map Marker V3.User can add Map Marker and additional info and this information is stored in sql Sever database. when the map page is loaded first time I retrieved all the markers stored in DB and display them on map. for Ajax call I am using WCF and Jquery. Every thing was working fine but one day I got an error

"Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property".

For this I increase the size of maxJsonLength as following:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

So for Now my application again working fine. My question is that is there any other way So that I can Increase this maxJsonLength at run time because I have to deliver this project to my client and if in future this same problem occurred this feature will stop working.
I also found some other example on stackoverflow
[Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/unlimited-for-maxjsonlength)

[maxjsonlength-property](http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/752/exception-message-error-during-serialization-or-deserialization-using-the-json-javascriptserializer-the-length-of-the-string-exceeds-the-value-set-on-the-maxjsonlength-property)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could set it to the max value 2147483644.

Probably your application will have serious performance problems before you hit the max value, so in a way it is unlimited since you will get other problems before you hit this liimtation.

There are problems with setting the limit very high:

- You are more vulnerable to a denial of service attack
- Your app could slow down and you get no information why (increasing payload size)

If I were you I would stick with the value you have now. And include info in the operations documentation that is they see that error they should increase the value.